# How do i make particles flow along this curve object?

Tags: animation, particles

This is my first post in this community. I recently started *blending* and I found it so much fun! The forum here is an amazing space!

Coming to my question, how do i make particles flow along this curve?[image] I tried with a **nurbs curve**, in which i added **curve guide force field**. It worked. But couldn't get the same with this hilbert curve. Tried **path animation**, the particles were flowing too fast and not smooth either. Please help me with this.
Thanks in advance.

[Download link](https://www.mediafire.com/file/1gjue2b73g8lyh5/Hillbert_cube_particle_flow.blend/file)

Answer (score 1):

Don't use a "curve guide", use the "force" ;)

1. Using a "**Force Field**" type "**Force**" on your curve.
2. Select shape "**Curve**"
3. Set the **Strength** to -25 (this affects the speed in which the particles flow along the curve)
4. The **Flow** value should be at least around 2.0, i used 3.5 (affects how much the particles stick to the curve, higher value, closer to/on the curve)
5. See to the lifetime of the particles and the end of spawning them, it will need a long .. i mean really long time to get through the curve you made (maybe raise the strength to compensate).
6. Eventually you can save and work over the curve like as in switch it to Bezier type so you can Clean up -> Decimate Curve to roughly 20% as in 0.2. (will get rid of most unnecessary points, after which you can switch it back to poly type)

That should do the trick, as you can see in the little visual demonstration:

[image: explanatory gif/video]